# \newcommand bug

Tags: macros

I am trying to define the following new command:

```
\newcommand{\kernel}[2]{k\left( #1, #2 \right)}
```

which when implemented via

```
$\kernel{\cdot}{Y}$
```

yields k(.,Y) (not sure how to reproduce the \cdot here)

which works, however I would like to set a default for the first argument to be \cdot, and I tried to do it via the following:

```
\newcommand{\kernel}[2][\cdot]{k\left( #1, #2 \right)}
```

however if I implement it via

```
$\kernel{}{Y}$
```

it gives `k(.,)Y` and not `k(.,Y)`!!!

This seems like a weird bug and I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it, I tried using `xparse` instead to define the command but I got the same bug. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it is an *optional* argument, you would say `$\kernel[]{Y}$` with **square** brackets around the optional (null) argument.

Comment: This is no bug but wrong usage ;-)

Comment: Isn't there already a `\ker` command that indicates the kernel of a vector space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given definition of the `\kernel` command is `ok`, but the calling is wrong. `[2][\cdot]` means that the first argument is optional and has be to called with `\kernel[foo]{Y}`,i.e. `[...]` indicates the optional argument.

In the code below I show an `xparse` version, also replacing `k` with a operator (expanding to k) and removing the `\left(...\right)` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\kernelop}{k}

\NewDocumentCommand{\kernel}{O{\cdot}m}{\kernelop(#1,#2)}


\begin{document}


$\kernel{Y}$

$\kernel[\oplus]{X}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I usually give some room to the dot, with `\,\cdot` or even `\,\cdot\,`.

Comment: @Manuel: That depends on **personal** preferences. The issue was the wrong usage of the command, I only improved it somewhat :-)